# ElasticSearch: What is the best way to find distinct dates in a daterange that contains documents?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-java-api

Let's say I have monthly indexes containing two fields that are important to filter a document: client_id and date_time, and several other fields of data I'm no interested in this query.

If I want to find all different date_time that exist in my index for a certain period of times (i.e. if it was orders, would be all the dates that were orders registered in the period, if it was rented cars, would be all the days there were rented cars, etc)

Let say I want to look for the different dateTime existing in ES for 2018-10-01 and 2018-10-03 (short for this example)

I can start with adding a bool query to limit this data to the date range:

```
{
  "size" : 0,
  "timeout" : 1500,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "range" : {
          "date_time" : {
            "from" : "2018-10-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "to" : "2018-10-03T23:59:59.999Z",
            "include_lower" : true,
            "include_upper" : true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I though of doing date range aggregation and filter by document count on the code:

```
{
  "size" : 0,
  "timeout" : 1500,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "range" : {
          "date_time" : {
            "from" : "2018-09-19T00:00:00.000Z",
            "to" : "2018-10-19T23:59:59.999Z",
            "include_lower" : true,
            "include_upper" : true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "date_range_agg" : {
      "date_range" : {
        "field" : "date_time",
        "ranges" : [ {
          "from" : "2018-09-30T00:00:00.000Z",
          "to" : "2018-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"
        }, {
          "from" : "2018-10-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "to" : "2018-10-02T00:00:00.000Z"
        }, {
          "from" : "2018-10-02T00:00:00.000Z",
          "to" : "2018-10-03T00:00:00.000Z"
        }, {
          "from" : "2018-10-03T00:00:00.000Z",
          "to" : "2018-10-04T00:00:00.000Z"
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can just filter the buckets from date_range_agg in my code, using doc_count > 0, but I still don't like it.

Is there a way to apply a filter on the date_range bucket to bring only those buckets that contains more than 0 doc count?

Is there another way to do a "sql group by" like agg of the date_time field to get all distinct one in ES for the date range?

**In short, I only need to get all different date_time that actually have documents in a given period of time.**

*We are talking about indexes with 7GB worth of documents (around 1.6 Million documents per index), or indexes of 3.8GB and 2 Million documents. So I'm trying to find the most performing way to retrieve this.*

ADDED- NOTE: *Actually, this query is used to validate the existence of data per day in all our indexes, some of them are really small, and some are huge like this, and can time out, all of them have a dateTime field, 
and all of them with the time stamp corresponding to millis of day 0, and same time zone, so they won't vary in milliseconds or anything*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below query is what you are looking for. I have implemented the `range part` of the `aggregation` using [date histogram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) and used [bucket selector aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) so that only those ranges having `document count>0` would be returned.

```
{  
   "size":0,
   "timeout":"1500ms",
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":{  
            "range":{  
               "date_time":{  
                  "from":"2018-09-19T00:00:00.000Z",
                  "to":"2018-10-19T23:59:59.999Z",
                  "include_lower":true,
                  "include_upper":true
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "aggregations":{  
      "date_range_agg":{  
         "date_histogram":{  
            "field":"date_time",
            "format":"MM-dd-yyyy",
            "interval":"week"
         },
         "aggs":{  
            "count_bucket_selector":{  
               "bucket_selector":{  
                  "buckets_path":{  
                     "count":"_count"
                  },
                  "script":{  
                     "lang":"expression",
                     "inline":"count>0"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

So the above query would return you the list of weeks along with the document count for that week. And if any that week doesn't have any documents, it would not display that week.

You can use `month` or `day` instead of `week` in the above query if you would like to see the details on monthly or daily basis respectively.

### Performance

Instead of specifying the `timeout`, I'd suggest you play around with [profiling](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/_profiling_aggregations.html) feature to give you an understanding of how long aggregation queries take to complete.

Below is how you can add profiling parameter to your query.

```
{
    "profile": true,
    "size": 0,
    "query": {}
}
```

You would be able to view a separate JSON object with `profile` in your response when you add this. In response you would be able to view the details of query performance for each and every shard. Check in particular the `aggregation` section and you can further refer to this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/_profiling_aggregations.html#_timing_breakdown_2) to know more on timing breakdown.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm so sorry it took me this long to reply, but just yesterday I was able to test your suggestion. Both of them (term agg) and datehistogram with bucket selector worked perfectly locally (even with 300 days range), but the time expended by the second approach (dateHistogram) almost half the time of the other. 
Now when I deployed both approaches in an environment more like production, the datehistogram  took almost a quarter or less than then term approach.

I'm really grateful to the two of you for your help, also for the advice with profiling. 

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

A date-range query with terms aggregation on datetype.keyword should return the unique dates as bucket ids

Comment: Thank you! It did work locally, saved half of the time my original query was taking, but in a production like environment, the histogram approach took almost the 4th part than this approach.
Thanks anyway.